# Что происходит во VLAN при переполнении таблицы коммутации (MAC-flooding)?

Tags: switch

Что будет происходить с VLAN, при атаках MAC-флудинга?

Я знаю, что в соответствии с таблицей коммутации коммутатор направляет поступившие кадры в соответствии с ней, позволяя транслировать поступившие кадры.

Также я знаю, что при атаке, в конечном итоге, для легитимного обмена между реальными участниками сети нужных записей в таблице комсутации не будет, и в соответствии со своим алгоритмом работы коммутатор будет ретранслировать поступающие кадры на все порты.

Что будет происходить при атаке в других вланах (vlan10, vlan20, например), если во vlan30 совершается атака.

Я знаю, что, так как таблица коммутации общая, должны пострадать все VLAN, но как? Помогите, пожайлуста, никак не могу понять

Comment: Дело даже не в таблице коммутации, а в том как именно пакет относится к нужному vlan. для этого в него вставляется тег, но тег вставляется уже после mac адресов, таким образом mac адреса пакетов точно такие же как и без vlan. (см. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.1Q) поэтому коммутатор будет работать абсолютно одинаково как без vlan так и с ними. И соответственно атака сделает то же самое, что и без vlan, за тем лишь исключением, что коммутатор при переполнении таблицы будет слать пакет не на все порты, а только на те, где разрешено прохождение данного vlan

Comment: Спасибо. А можно как-то узнать, как именно разрешено прохождение vlan к портам?

Comment: Или имеется ввиду, что пакеты будут пересылаться в рамках одного vlan. Тогда на другой пересылаться они не будут?

Comment: пакеты vlan10 будут пересылаться на порты где разрешен 10 vlan и на порты где есть только 20, а 10 нет не будут. В принципе никакого отличия от обычной работы в состояниях под атакой/без атаки опять же нет. Если записи нет в таблице (например в последнее время данный mac ничего не посылал и соотв его нет в таблице) то пакет точно так же будет послан на все разрешенные порты данного vlan

Comment: Понял, спасибо большое